# RabbitMQ health check failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm using Spring Boot and running RabbitMQ inside docker container. All works well except Rabbit health check problem. Which means I can't queue messages from my web app.

This is exact error I have in my app:

```
[n(14)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.a.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator       : Rabbit health check failed
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:74) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
```

[image]

How I can fix it?

Comment: Is there any related code that you can post? Or is this inherent to your configuration?

Comment: @Vnuuk At risk of stating the obvious, can you please check if the connection parameters are correct and port on Docker container is exposed properly? Looks like RabbitMQ is unreachable.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?